# Export sqlite data to csv with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am having a simple application that gets data from sqlite  using entity framework core, and of course by pagination because there is a lot of data. Now I was wondering is there a simple way to export it to csv. I could use the same method same way as pagination(if I will dump all data to memory i will get out of memory exception) get part of data per page and add it to csv, and i know there is a way to export data directly from sqlite using:

```
>sqlite3 c:/sqlite/chinook.db
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output data.csv
```

My Entity framework method looks like:

```
    public IEnumerable<Event> PaginationOrderedGet(int currentPage, int pageSize)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            //Add something to export to csv
            IQueryable<Event> query = ctx.Events.Where(e => e.CorrectEntry && !e.DuplicatedEntry);
            IQueryable<Event> paginationQuery = query.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            return paginationQuery.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to combine it so i can just send this request directly do DB to export to csv.

Comment: If memory is an issue you could, as you said, use the same paging code to do the export in batches. Read one page of data -> Write to file, Read second page of data -> append write to same file

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of paged export code using your pagination method, something along these lines:

```
int currentPage = 1;
int pageSize = 1000;


var data = PaginationOrderedGet(currentPage, pageSize)
while(data.Count() != 0) {
   foreach(var item in data){
       File.AppendAllText(@"C:\path\to\file.csv", GetItemAsCsv(item) + Environment.NewLine);
   }
   currentPage++;
   data = PaginationOrderedGet(currentPage, pageSize)
}
```